# IPTables Rules Being Loaded From Somewhere

Tags: iptables, startup, csf

I'm having troubles connecting (meaning I can't connect to any IP or port) to my server and it appears that the problem was to do with CSF. I uninstalled CSF (by running /etc/csf/uninstall.sh) and restarted the server. I was still unable to connect. I ran `iptables -F` and then `service iptables save`. I was then able to connect, but then once I reboot the server I'm blocked again. I ran `iptables -L` to see if theres any rules still and I got this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
spooflist  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:!FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN state NEW
DROP       all  -f  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,PSH,URG
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/NONE limit: avg 5/min burst 7 LOG level warning prefix `NULL Packets'
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/NONE
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN,RST
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN/FIN,SYN limit: avg 5/min burst 7 LOG level warning prefix `XMAS Packets'
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN/FIN,SYN
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,ACK/FIN limit: avg 5/min burst 7 LOG level warning prefix `Fin Packets Scan'
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,ACK/FIN
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,SYN,RST,ACK,URG
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            PKTTYPE = broadcast
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            PKTTYPE = multicast
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID
ACCEPT     tcp  --  21.167.10.204.IN-ADDR.ARPA.HSIPT.AS46600.NET  18.167.10.204.IN-ADDR.ARPA.HSIPT.AS46600.NET tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  21.167.10.204.IN-ADDR.ARPA.HSIPT.AS46600.NET  18.167.10.204.IN-ADDR.ARPA.HSIPT.AS46600.NET tcp dpt:ndmp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  21.167.10.204.IN-ADDR.ARPA.HSIPT.AS46600.NET  18.167.10.204.IN-ADDR.ARPA.HSIPT.AS46600.NET tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  21.167.10.204.IN-ADDR.ARPA.HSIPT.AS46600.NET  18.167.10.204.IN-ADDR.ARPA.HSIPT.AS46600.NET tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED limit: avg 30/sec burst 5
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp destination-unreachable limit: avg 30/sec burst 5
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp redirect limit: avg 30/sec burst 5
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp time-exceeded limit: avg 30/sec burst 5
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 5/min burst 7 LOG level warning
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
spooflist  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain spooflist (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  loopback/8           anywhere            LOG level warning prefix `SPOOF List Block'
DROP       all  --  loopback/8           anywhere
LOG        all  --  192.168.0.0/16       anywhere            LOG level warning prefix `SPOOF List Block'
DROP       all  --  192.168.0.0/16       anywhere
LOG        all  --  172.16.0.0/12        anywhere            LOG level warning prefix `SPOOF List Block'
DROP       all  --  172.16.0.0/12        anywhere
LOG        all  --  10.0.0.0/8           anywhere            LOG level warning prefix `SPOOF List Block'
DROP       all  --  10.0.0.0/8           anywhere
LOG        all  --  link-local/16        anywhere            LOG level warning prefix `SPOOF List Block'
DROP       all  --  link-local/16        anywhere
LOG        all  --  default/8            anywhere            LOG level warning prefix `SPOOF List Block'
DROP       all  --  default/8            anywhere
LOG        all  --  240.0.0.0/4          anywhere            LOG level warning prefix `SPOOF List Block'
DROP       all  --  240.0.0.0/4          anywhere
LOG        all  --  255.255.255.255      anywhere            LOG level warning prefix `SPOOF List Block'
DROP       all  --  255.255.255.255      anywhere
LOG        all  --  168.254.0.0/16       anywhere            LOG level warning prefix `SPOOF List Block'
DROP       all  --  168.254.0.0/16       anywhere
LOG        all  --  base-address.mcast.net/4  anywhere            LOG level warning prefix `SPOOF List Block'
DROP       all  --  base-address.mcast.net/4  anywhere
LOG        all  --  240.0.0.0/5          anywhere            LOG level warning prefix `SPOOF List Block'
DROP       all  --  240.0.0.0/5          anywhere
LOG        all  --  248.0.0.0/5          anywhere            LOG level warning prefix `SPOOF List Block'
DROP       all  --  248.0.0.0/5          anywhere
LOG        all  --  192.0.2.0/24         anywhere            LOG level warning prefix `SPOOF List Block'
DROP       all  --  192.0.2.0/24         anywhere
```

I ran `lsmod|grep ip` to see what IPTables modules are loaded and it seems the same as all my other servers:

```
ipt_REJECT              2351  0
ipt_LOG                 5845  0
ip6t_REJECT             4628  2
nf_conntrack_ipv6       8337  2
nf_defrag_ipv6         27236  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
nf_conntrack           80390  2 nf_conntrack_ipv6,xt_state
ip6table_filter         2889  1
ip6_tables             18732  1 ip6table_filter
ipv6                  334740  25 ip6t_REJECT,nf_conntrack_ipv6,nf_defrag_ipv6
```

Here's a list of services that run on startup (and `/etc/rc/rc.local` is the default file)

```
auditd          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
blk-availability        0:off   1:on    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
cgconfig        0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
crond           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
ip6tables       0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
iptables        0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
lvm2-monitor    0:off   1:on    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
mysql           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
named           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
netconsole      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
netfs           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
network         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
portreserve     0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
postfix         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
restorecond     0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
rsyslog         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
sshd            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
udev-post       0:off   1:on    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Some more notes:

- I had KVM and OpenVZ installed on this server but removed them. I don't see anything that would cause the rules to load, but maybe I'm not looking good enough?
- I don't see any crontab rules that would affect IPTables.

I have tried everything to remove these but they still keep on showing up after I reboot. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem which was a script that was being loaded on startup. I had [this script](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-rhel-linux-openvz-hardware-node-iptables-firewall/) being called in `/etc/rc.local` in order for the internet to work properly with OpenVZ containers. I removed the script and now I'm able to connect to the server.